# find the height of a class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have many child divs with same class name. Out of all the divs only one div will appear based on the users selection and other divs will be set to `display: none;`.

How can I find out the height of the class which is currently in `display: block`? I tried using ids but it wasn't possible since I have many divs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Karna i think he means how many divs in parent

Comment: show what you have tried, and share some html and javascript, id's are limited to one element per view maybe you should use classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `:visible`:

```
var height = $('.class:visible').css('height'); // will give you css height
var height = $('.class:visible').height(); // will give you calculated height
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the common class to select all the `div` elements, then use the `:visible` selector to access the one which is currently displayed. From there you can access the `height()` property. Something like this:

```
var height = $('.elements:visible').height();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say your elements has classname `childdivs`, you can use `:visible` selector to target visible element:

```
 $('.childdivs:visible').height()
```

Answer (score 0):

Mutiple Ways

1. `$(".highlight:visible").height();`
2. `$('.highlight[style*="block"]').height();`